# error: QT 5.0 QTreeWidget include not found

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

In manual for QTreeWidget it states that we have to:

## include

however when I do that I get error:

d:*****************: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QTreeWidget': No such file or directory

However #include  gets found.

Where does it go wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add *QT += widgets* (to link with the widgets module) into your .pro file, then *run qmake* and then build your project.

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem. In former versions of QT it was not needed?

Comment: No it wasn't needed in Qt 4, only in Qt 5, because the QWidget derived classes were in Gui module in Qt 4 and were moved to Widgets module in Qt 5, more information can be found in the documentation, here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtwidgets-index.html and here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/modules.html

LE: also see this doc page: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5